# Strictly using "localhost" instead of "localhost:8888" Mac MAMP possible?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I just switched from windows to Mac. I used MAMP for my web development, and with it I could go to "localhost" and it would connect to the server. Now after installing MAMP on a Mac, "localhost" I get Macs native It works!, not my index. If I go to "localhost:8888" it does go to the index though. Is there a way to just use localhost?

Comment: So, you need something like a 301 redirect to point http over port 80 to port 8888? [Could you edit a link to the MAMP version you chose and your macOS version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/448047/edit) into the body of the question, as well?

Comment: It's been a while since I fiddled with MAMP but can't you change what port it listens on in the MAMP Preference panel or App? Then just turn off Internet Sharing in the Sharing Preferences Pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as designed. Your MAMP is running on port 8888, so if you navigate to localhost it tries to load the default port 80 (http://localhost:80) (or :443 for https) and finds nothing.

You need to adjust your software to run on the port you'd prefer – in this case port 80 (again, or 443 if you're using https).

Comment: One probably also needs to disable the default httpd currently listening on port 80.